# How to encode multiple sentences using transformers.BertTokenizer?

Tags: word-embedding, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I would like to create a minibatch by encoding multiple sentences using transform.BertTokenizer. It seems working for a single sentence. How to make it work for several sentences?

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# tokenize a single sentence seems working
tokenizer.encode('this is the first sentence')
>>> [2023, 2003, 1996, 2034, 6251]

# tokenize two sentences
tokenizer.encode(['this is the first sentence', 'another sentence'])
>>> [100, 100] # expecting 7 tokens
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**transformers >= 4.0.0**:
Use `__call__` method of the [tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase). It will generate a dictionary which contains the `input_ids`, `token_type_ids` and the `attention_mask` as list for each input sentence:

```py
tokenizer(['this is the first sentence', 'another setence'])
```

Output:

```
{'input_ids': [[101, 2023, 2003, 1996, 2034, 6251, 102], [101, 2178, 2275, 10127, 102]], 'token_type_ids': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]}
```

**transformers < 4.0.0**:
Use `tokenizer.batch_encode_plus` ([documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.batch_encode_plus)). It will generate a dictionary which contains the `input_ids`, `token_type_ids` and the `attention_mask` as list for each input sentence:

```py
tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(['this is the first sentence', 'another setence'])
```

Output:

```
{'input_ids': [[101, 2023, 2003, 1996, 2034, 6251, 102], [101, 2178, 2275, 10127, 102]], 'token_type_ids': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]}
```

**Applies to **call** and batch_encode_plus:**
In case you only want to generate the input_ids, you have to set `return_token_type_ids` and `return_attention_mask` to False:

```py
tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(['this is the first sentence', 'another setence'], return_token_type_ids=False, return_attention_mask=False)
```

Output:

```
{'input_ids': [[101, 2023, 2003, 1996, 2034, 6251, 102], [101, 2178, 2275, 10127, 102]]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I got the error: AttributeError: 'BertTokenizer' object has no attribute 'batch_encode_plus'. Does the tokenizer in yor answer refer to some other object?

Comment: @LeiHao No, maybe your are using an older transformers version? Which version do you use?

Comment: It's 2.1.1. I installed it using Conda. Which version are you using?

Comment: 3.0.0 but you need to install it from pip directly and not conda. Create a new conda environment and install everything via pip.

Comment: Can you provide document to `tokenizer.batch_encode_plus`? It will add some more value to the answer.

Comment: I think we can also do without batch_encode_plus... `tokenizer(['this is the first sentence', 'another setence'], return_token_type_ids=False, return_attention_mask=False)`

Comment: For decoding of multiple sentences: `tokenizer.batch_decode(ids)`

Answer (score 0):

What you did is almost correct. You can pass the sentences as a list to the tokenizer.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
two_sentences = ['this is the first sentence', 'another sentence']


tokenized_sentences = tokenizer(two_sentences)
```

The last line of code makes the difference.

The `tokenized_sentences` is a dict with the containing the following information

> {'input_ids': [[101, 2023, 2003, 1996, 2034, 6251, 102], [101, 2178, 6251, 102]], 'token_type_ids': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]], 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]}

where the list of sentences produces a list of tokenized sentences stored under the `input_ids` key.

'this is the first sentence' = [101, 2023, 2003, 1996, 2034, 6251, 102] and 'another sentence' = [101, 2178, 6251, 102].

101 is the start token. 102 is the stop token.